# How can I change the CurrentCulture of the entire process (not just current thread) in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

I have a situation where I need to set my process' locale to en-US.

I know how to do this for the current thread:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

But my application uses `BackgroundWorkers` to do some processing, and the locale for these worker threads seems not to be affected by the above change to their spawning main-thread.

So how can I set the locale for all the threads in my application without setting it in each one manually?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to change the operating system locale if you want to do that. For what reason do you want BackgroundWorkers to run in en-US?

You should have your business layer running in an invariant culture, and only have a specific culture for the end user's UI.

If you are using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component, and have to do this you could try something like this in the DoWork method:

```
// In DoWork
System.Globalization.CultureInfo before = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
try

{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
 // Proceed with specific code
}

finally
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = before;
}
```

Comment: The background worker may very well be running in the UI layer (as a `BackgroundWorker` component on a `Form` for instance)

Comment: @Fredrik- Yes (especially if it is the Background Worker component), but you don't update the UI on the background worker thread. At least you don't if you are using it properly.

Comment: The background worker does double.Parse(string) on some input, which breaks for certain locales that have weird decimal point representations. So, I still need to know how to set the locale for the entire process. Are you saying this isn't possible?

Comment: Assaf- can you post a code sample. Do none of my suggestions work for you?

Comment: I ended up inheriting from BW and setting the CurrentCulture before every thread function...

Comment: Assaf- sounds like a good approach- especially if you want to reuse the functionality in other places.

Answer (score 13):

With 4.0, you will need to manage this yourself by setting the culture for each thread. But with 4.5, you can define a culture for the appdomain and that is the preferred way to handle this. The relevant apis are [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It's important that this is done before any service registrations etc. otherwise they might be created with the old culture.

Answer (score 2):

We use helper class for BackgroudWorker like this:

```
public static class BackgroundWorkerHelper
{
public static void RunInBackground(Action doWorkAction, Action completedAction, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (_, args) =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            doWorkAction.Invoke();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, args) =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            completedAction.Invoke();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
BackgroundWorkerHelper.RunInBackground(() => { Work(); }, () => { AfterWork(); },Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID);//Pass the LCID as argument
```

after on do work make this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(int.Parse(e.Argument.ToString()));
```

Comment: +1 for using a culture identifier instead of a culture name. This is necessary to separate `Spanish - Spain` from `Spanish - Spain`, for example, where `0x0C0A` uses international sort order and `0x040A` uses traditional sort order. REF: [CultureInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)