# How to set up UI culture for all the threads in framework 4.0?

Tags: c#

I want to set UI culture for all the threads that are currently running.
here is my code

```
 ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

 foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
 {
      //How do i set UI culture here.
 }
```

otherwise is there any other way to do it. I am using 4.0.
I Know that in 4.5 we have the following

```
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture
```

How do i achieve it in earlier versions. atleast in 4.0?

Comment: there is no property called CurrentCulture for ProcessThread

Comment: Note that not even `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` will change the culture of threads that are already running.

Comment: Ok Matthew Watson. Do you know any other way to do it.

Comment: .Net doesn't give you any direct way to get a list of all the managed threads that are running, so you can't easily do this. Also, even if you could it would be potentially dangerous - what if you change the culture for a thread that was partway through retrieving resources? What about threadpool threads that are re-used many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460023/how-can-i-change-the-currentculture-of-the-entire-process-not-just-current-thre).

If you want to change the culture of `ProcessThread` then you have to change the operating system locale.

Comment: thread you mentioned here is an instance of Thread. But I asked is for ProcessThread. Look at my question.

Comment: but still they both are not same `CurrentCulture` != `CurrentUICulture`

Answer (score 0):

If you create the thread, you can use Thread.CurrentCulture to change the culture.